# Pulling and displaying YQL financial data with jquery and displaying it with .html()

Tags: javascript, html, json, yql

I'm having an issue with the .html() function and YQL pulled data. The data is pulling (the data can be seen if using the YQL console), but it is not showing or displaying any results.

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<ul id="TECO-container">
    <li class="high">High: </li>
    <li class="low">Low: </li>
    <li class="close">Closing: </li>
    <li class="volume">Volume: </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
// initialise plugins
jQuery(function () {
    tecoGetQuote('TECO');
});

//The above function is on a different .js than the below script.

var tecoGetQuote = function (symbol) {
    var yqlURL = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=";
    var dataFormat = "&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
    var realtimeQ = yqlURL + "select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22" + symbol + "%22)%0A%09%09&" + dataFormat;
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON(realtimeQ, function (json) { //YQL Request
            //console.log(json.query.results.quote);
            //<li class="high">High: -</li><li class="low">Low: -</li><li class="close">Closing: -</li><li class="volume">Volume: -</li>
            $('#TECO-container .high').html('High: <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#FFBB00">' + json.query.results.quote.DaysHigh + '</span>');
            $('#TECO-container .low').html('Low: <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#FFBB00">' + json.query.results.quote.DaysLow + '</span>');
            $('#TECO-container .close').html('Closing: <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#FFBB00">' + json.query.results.quote.PreviousClose + '</span>');
            $('#TECO-container .volume').html('Volume: <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#FFBB00">' + addCommas(json.query.results.quote.Volume) + '</span>');
        });
    });
};
```

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Darthfuzzy/cPFKE/4/

According to JSFiddle, the HTML/JS is completely valid. All indications show that it should run too. The result should just display the current market data and I've seen similar functions displayed on sites before. I just cannot figure out where the JS is not running.

The script should be fairly straight forward: The stock ticker is 'TECO' (defined as tecoGetQuote). That function then pulls the financial data from the YQL JSON then prints the data. Yet for some reason, no matter how I change the stuff, it doesn't display.

Could someone please help me by pointing to where the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone was wondering, there was no issue with the coding, rather there was an issue with the callback=? not being added into the JS which resulted in an access control allow origin issue.

[XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Changing the var dataformat line to:

```
var dataFormat ="&callback=&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
```

Solved the issue.